# How do I modify the rpm spec file to require java-1.8.0-openjdk on centos 7?

Tags: centos, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I normally start with a [Minimal Centos 7](http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/7/isos/x86_64/) and run

```
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk
```

in order to install a Java Runtime Environment.  This works perfectly as I am able to execute JAR files.

I am now trying to create an [RPM](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/how-manage-packages) [spec file](https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/spec.html) that uses the "[Requires](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch-dependencies.html)" clause to package dependencies like:

```
Requires:        jre-headless = 1.8
```

However, when I do

```
yum install my-rpm-1.0.0.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

I get error messages that look like:

```
Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.272.b10-1.el7_9.i686
Available: 1:java-11-openjdk-headless-11.04.11-0.el7_6.i686
    Not found

You could try using --skip-broken to work around this problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with my "Requires:" clause in my spec file? I just want the spec file to automatically do "yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk" via the "Requires" clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anything provides `jre-headless = 1.8`. Let's take a look at the available virtual packages:

```
$ repoquery --provides $(repoquery --whatprovides jre-headless) | sort -u | grep jre-headless
jre-headless = 1:1.7.0
jre-headless = 1:1.8.0
```

So you could write:

```
Requires: jre-headless = 1:1.8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

`1.8` does not suffice due to the epoch number involved in the package
version name (the funny `1:` prefix);

```
# rpm -qa | grep head
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.332.b09-1.el7_9.x86_64
# rpm -q --provides java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless | grep jre
jre-1.8.0-headless = 1:1.8.0.332.b09-1.el7_9
jre-1.8.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.8.0.332.b09-1.el7_9
jre-headless = 1:1.8.0
jre-openjdk-headless = 1:1.8.0.332.b09-1.el7_9
```

if instead `1:1.8.0` is used this should satisfy the dependency
resolution:

```
# grep Requ somedirectory.spec
Requires:       jre-headless = 1:1.8.0
# rpmbuild -ba somedirectory.spec
...
# rpm -qp --requires rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/somedirectory*
jre-headless = 1:1.8.0 
# yum -y install /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/somedirectory*
...
```