# How do you modify the RPM spec file to require perl libraries on centos 7?

Tags: centos, perl, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I normally start with a [Minimal Centos 7](http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/7/isos/x86_64/) and run

```
yum install perl-libs.x86_64
```

This works perfectly.

I am now trying to create an [RPM](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/how-manage-packages) [spec file](https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/spec.html) that uses the "[Requires](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch-dependencies.html)" clause to package dependencies like:

```
Requires:        perl-libs.x86_64
```

However, when I do

```
yum install my-rpm-1.0.0.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

I get error messages that look like:

```
Requires: perl-libs(x86_64) = 4:5.16.3-299.el7_9
Available: 4:perl-libs-5.16.3-293.el7.x86_64
Available: 4:perl-libs-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64


You could try using --skip-broken to work around this problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with my "Requires:" clause in my spec file? I just want the spec file to automatically do "yum install perl-libs" via the "Requires" clause.

Comment: Try to use `perl-libs`  without adding the architecture. Also it would help if you post your `.spec` file.

Comment: same way as in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/709042/how-do-i-modify-the-rpm-spec-file-to-require-java-1-8-0-openjdk-on-centos-7 but getting the version of the perl module instead of the java module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding a dependency on `perl-libs`, a better practice is using Perl dependency generators. This can be achieved by simply including the following:

```
BuildRequires:  perl-generators
```

Not only it will make your resulting package set up with Perl runtime as a dependency, but also will attempt to detect any Perl module packages your program needs and set them up as dependencies as well.

Comment: when I tried this, I get an error message "Failed build dependencies: perl-generators is needed by  my-rpm-1.0.0.el7.x86_64"

Comment: Surely need to install build dependencies before building: `yum-builddep you.spec`